# Submit hidden input value with jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have just started using jQuery autocomplete and for simple searches this works well. However, what I would like to do is send a hidden input with a value to search.php to refine my search.

For example, when autocomplete sends data to search.php it uses term and this is evaluated in search.php as `$_GET['term']`. What I need to do is send a hidden input with a value and extract the value in search.php something like `$_GET['hidden'];`

Is this possible in autocomplete. Thanks

```
$(function () {
  $(".search").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var v = ui.item.value;
      console.log(v);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a parameter as query string. If your input hidden as id equals to hidden(it's only an example), so:

```
$(function () {
    var hidden = $('#hidden').val();
    $(".search").autocomplete({
      source: "search.php?parameter="+hidden,
      minLength: 2,
      select: function (event, ui) {
        var v = ui.item.value;
        console.log(v);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```